# Convert Date from DD-MMM-YYYY to YYYY-MMM-DD using xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a XML that has a date formatted as (2019-Aug-19) (YYYY-MMM-DD).

I want this to be transformed to (2019-08-19) (YYYY-MM-DD)

Hear is a sample what i have done. But no luck

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(concat(date, T00:00:00Z')), '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]')"/>
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036624/convert-date-format-in-xslt-from-yyyymmdd-to-mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: @RamaSh issue is  `YYYY-MMM-DD` format. I can't convert `Aug` - `MMM` to '08' .

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446199/converting-dates-from-names-to-numbers-in-xslt

Comment: @Rupesh_Kr Thanks . currntly i'm doing that way. but is their way to direct convert `MMM` to `MM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go may be another simple method:

**XML:**

```
<time>2019-Aug-19T00:00:00Z</time>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="dt" select="time"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(replace($dt, substring-before(substring-after($dt,'-'),'-') ,format-number(index-of(('jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov', 'dec'),lower-case(substring-before(substring-after(lower-case($dt),'-'), '-'))),'00'))),'[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**Result:**

```
19-08-2019
```

**For YYYY-MM-DD you can do:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(replace($dt, substring-before(substring-after($dt,'-'),'-') ,format-number(index-of(('jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov', 'dec'),lower-case(substring-before(substring-after(lower-case($dt),'-'), '-'))),'00'))),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')"/>
```

**Result:**

```
2019-08-19
```

See Link: http://xsltransform.net/nbiCsZm